# How to mitigate an unmounted bathtub faucet from back wall access

Tags: plumbing, faucet, bathtub

The pictured bathtub faucet pex hookup is not mounted, but I have back-wall access through a panel provided by the previous owner under a cabinet.

[image: back of tub faucet installation]

The faucet can be pulled several inches into the tub. Without removing the tub, what is the best way to mount this or a replacement fitting from the back for a professional and long term result?

Comment: Normally a faucet is mounted on a wood brace , well all the ones I have installed with galvanized, copper and PVC were screwed to a wooden brace for support. I see only a single tube with a 90 , but when I did tubs and showers I used 90’s with lugs for supports. Not a plumber but this is how I did quite a few homes befor my dad died and many remodels I did on the side after.

Comment: I can imagine a clamping flange which would hold the faucet tight to the tub from the back side. This must be a common part used in plumbing these fiberglass tubs.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the incorrect fitting, replace with a drop-ear elbow, and mount a hunk of wood to mount the drop ear elbow to. This will be awkward and annoying to do (through that hole) but should be possible. You may (or will) need a longer hunk of pipe for the tub spout mount.

Other ways might be possible, but will be kludges, (like the "giant glob of construction adhesive" approach. Easier to do, but a definite kludge.)

Whoever did this install was an idiot. A tub only install needs one drop ear elbow, a tub/shower install needs two, they are made, and this is what they are made for.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a clamp out of two 2" x 4" pieces of wood 0.5" or 0.75" thick which would hold the fitting against the tub. Two screws or two bolts in the plane of the tub would pull the two pieces of wood together around the fitting. You could cut or rasp notches in the two pieces to keep them in place as the clamp is tightened.